# How do I write a background service that restarts when notified by API methods?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, background-process

I have a background service that does some processing of records in a DB. If there are no records left to process, the service should be idle. An HTTP POST method in the application to endpoint X may allow for a new record to be inserted, necessitating that the background service starts running again.

Importantly, records must be processed sequentially, according to some order. These jobs cannot be parallelised, as they affect the state of an external system.

It's possible for a job to be paused due to some condition not being met. In this case, other jobs should not start, as they may depend on the first one being completed.

Processing of each record may take some time, so if two records are inserted in quick succession the background service should ignore the notification output by the second insertion, as it will likely still be processing the first. I **do not want** to busy-wait, e.g.

```
while (true)
{
    if (db.HasRecordsToProcess())
    {
        _recordProcessor.ProcessRecords();
    }
}
```

nor do I want to Thread.Sleep, i.e.

```
while (true)
{
    if (db.HasRecordsToProcess())
    {
        _recordProcessor.ProcessRecords();
    } else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Instead, I want the service to do nothing until the API method tells it to wake up. Below is some of the code I've written.

```
    public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IRecordProcessor _recordProcessor;
        private readonly AutoResetEvent _isRunning = new AutoResetEvent(true);
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        //... constructor...

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            await Task.Yield(); // Required for the method to be executed asynchronously on startup.            
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _isRunning.WaitOne();
                _recordProcessor.ProcessRecords(); // do some long-running work
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies the background service to resume processing records.
        /// </summary>
        public void Resume()
        {
            _isRunning.Set();
        }
    }
```

```
    public interface IRecordProcessor
    {
        void ProcessRecords();
    }
```

The implementation of `IRecordProcessor` looks something like this:

```
        public void ProcessRecords()
        {
            var isRunning = true;
            while (isRunning)
            {
                // this is basically the db.HasRecordsToProcess bit from the pseudocode in the 
                // first two examples of my question, showing busy-waiting / Thread.Sleeping
                var queueHead = db.GetRecords.OrderBy(m => m.StartTime).FirstOrDefault();

                isRunning = queueHead != null;
                if (!isRunning) continue;
                heavyweightProcessor.Process(queueHead); // this might take a few minutes
            }
        }
```

The implementation thus handles a case where a record is being processed, and while that's happening another record is inserted. When it loops again, it will find the other record and just continue processing.

An API method where the background service can be told to restart:

```
[HttpPost("record", Name = "CreateRecordToProcess")]
public ActionResult<CreatedRecord> CreateRecordToProcess()
{
    var record = _someDbService.CreateSomeResource();
    _backgroundService.Resume();
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetRecordToProcess", new { id = record.Id}, (Record) record);
}
```

### Is there a more idiomatic way to define this behaviour in .NET?

As mentioned, there are a couple of cases where I want well-defined behaviour:

1. If the background service is processing a record, and a second record is inserted, then the service should carry on as if it received no notification. By extension, if the service is processing a record and N new records are inserted for it to process, it
2. If the background service is not processing a record, it should wait (without `Thread.Sleep` or busy-waiting) until a relevant resource is saved, at which point it should be notified -- by the API method that saved the resource -- to start querying the DB again to get records to process.

### How do I test this?

Test at the moment:

```
var mockProcessor = new MockRecordProcessor(_testOutputHelper);
_backgroundService = new MyBackgroundService(...otherDependencies, mockProcessor);

var token = new CancellationToken();
await _backgroundService.StartAsync(token);
Thread.Sleep(10_000);
_backgroundService.Resume();
Thread.Sleep(10_000);
Assert.Equal(2, mockProcessor.Count);
```

I would obviously prefer not to do the `Thread.Sleep` in this test, but I can't work out how to specify a condition in the test like "wait for initial processing to finish before explicitly notifying the service to resume with `_backgroundService.Resume`".

Comment: Sorry to say that but it seems that you are trying to reinvent the wheel. There are free libraries that will do that for you with a lot of configuration options. For example [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Comment: @Steve this is why I'm asking for advice about more standard ways to achieve this. I'm aware I'm not the first person to want to do this, I'm just not familiar enough with the .NET ecosystem to know what to look for.

Comment: @Steve as an aside, these jobs have to be run sequentially - there's no concept of two `ProcessRecords` happening simultaneously, as they affect the state of an external system.

Comment: Have you considered using a Queue instead?

Comment: @Nkosi see my edit :)